# Simple Kanban component

Tags: react.js, jsx

I am looking for some suggestions on how to make my code cleaner and simpler. Or put another way: more elegant and idiomatic. Any other comments on quality or anything would be appreciated.

```
class App extends Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            colIds : ["winnie", "bob", "thomas", "george"], 
            cols : [
              {name:"Winnnie", headerColor: "#8E6E95", id : "winnie" },
              {name:"Bob",  headerColor: "#39A59C", id :"bob"},
              {name:"Thomas",  headerColor: "#344759", id: "thomas"},
              {name:"George",  headerColor: "#E8741E", id: "george"}
            ],
            cards : [
              {colid: "winnie", task: "buy eggs"},
              {colid: "bob", task: "clean basement"},
              {colid: "thomas", task: "pack"},
              {colid: "george", task: "pay bills"},
            ]
          }

          this.addCard = this.addCard.bind(this);
          this.moveCardRight = this.moveCardRight.bind(this);
          this.moveCardLeft = this.moveCardLeft.bind(this);
      }

      getColCards(colid){
          let cards = this.state.cards.filter( c => c.colid == colid);
          return cards;
      }

      addCard(colid){
        let cardTask = window.prompt("Whats the task you want to add");
        let currentCards = this.state.cards.slice();
        let newCard = {colid: colid, task: cardTask};
        currentCards.push(newCard);
        this.setState({cards: currentCards});

      }
      moveCardRight(card){
        let currentCardCol = card.colid;
        let nextIndex =  this.state.colIds.indexOf(currentCardCol) + 1;

        if(nextIndex > this.state.colIds.length - 1 ){
          return null;
        }
        let currentCards = this.state.cards.slice();
        for(let i = 0; i < currentCards.length; i++){
            if(currentCards[i].task === card.task){
               currentCards[i] = {
                 ...currentCards[i],
                 colid : this.state.colIds[nextIndex]
               }
            }
        }
        this.setState({cards: currentCards});
      }

      moveCardLeft(card){
        let currentCardCol = card.colid;
        let nextIndex =  this.state.colIds.indexOf(currentCardCol) - 1;

        if(nextIndex < 0 ){
          return null;
        }
        let currentCards = this.state.cards.slice();
        for(let i = 0; i < currentCards.length; i++){
            if(currentCards[i].task === card.task){
               currentCards[i] = {
                 ...currentCards[i],
                 colid : this.state.colIds[nextIndex]
               }
            }
        }
        this.setState({cards: currentCards});
      }
      render() {
        let cols =[  
                      {name:"Winnnie", headerColor: "#8E6E95"},
                      {name:"Bob",  headerColor: "#39A59C"},
                      {name:"Thomas",  headerColor: "#344759"},
                      {name:"George",  headerColor: "#E8741E"}
        ];
        let colCards = this.state.cols.map(c => {
        let cards = this.getColCards(c.id).map(c =>  {
            return <div>
                    <span onClick = {() => this.moveCardLeft(c)}> {"<   "} </span> 
                    {c.task}   
                    <span onClick = {() => this.moveCardRight(c)}> {"    >"} </span> 
                   </div> 
          })

          return  <CardCol  name={c.name}  headerColor={c.headerColor} addCard={this.addCard} id={c.id}>
                     {cards}
                  </CardCol>
        })
        return (
          <div className="App">
          {colCards}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] you post to include the code for the `CardCol` component? And are the `moveCardLeft()` and `moveCardRight()` functions supposed to move the cards left and right? if so, does that currently work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation is great and works well, but there are some things you could change.

#### Eliminate repetitive code

You have two large methods, `moveCardLeft` and `moveCardRight`, that do almost the same thing. These can either be combined entirely or the matching code can be separated out to a new method and referenced by the original two. For my example, I chose the former:

```
moveCard(card, dir) {
  let nextIndex = this.state.colIds.indexOf(card.colid);

  if (dir === "left") nextIndex--;
  else if (dir === "right") nextIndex++;
  else return null;

  if (nextIndex < 0 || nextIndex > this.state.colIds.length - 1) {
    return null;
  }

  let currentCards = this.state.cards.slice();
  for (let i = 0; i < currentCards.length; i++) {
    if (currentCards[i].task === card.task) {
      currentCards[i] = {
        ...currentCards[i],
        colid: this.state.colIds[nextIndex]
      }
    }
  }
  this.setState({ cards: currentCards });
}
```

With this, you just have to pass in an extra parameter for the direction (left or right). It eliminates the repetition which is almost always beneficial.

#### Use consistent formatting

This includes indentation, new lines, and general spacing.

As you have it written in your post (maybe this is just a copy/paste error), the `map` inside of a `map` in your render method is not indented properly, which will undoubtedly confuse you at some point. Here is what it should look like:

```
render() {
  let cols = [
    { name: "Winnnie", headerColor: "#8E6E95" },
    { name: "Bob", headerColor: "#39A59C" },
    { name: "Thomas", headerColor: "#344759" },
    { name: "George", headerColor: "#E8741E" }
  ];
  let colCards = this.state.cols.map(c => {
    let cards = this.getColCards(c.id).map(c => {
      return (
        <div>
          <span onClick={() => this.moveCard(c, "left")}>{"<   "}</span>
            {c.task}
          <span onClick={() => this.moveCard(c, "right")}>{"    >"}</span>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <CardCol name={c.name} headerColor={c.headerColor} addCard={this.addCard} id={c.id}>
        {cards}
      </CardCol>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {colCards}
    </div>
  )
}
```

#### Other thoughts

- Use strict equality (`===`) by default and only fall back to loose/abstract equality (`==`) when absolutely necessary.
- Consider how much more concise your code could be if you got rid of the `colIds` and simply used the `cols` instead to organize the cards. Additionally, consider placing the `cards` inside of their respective `cols` instead of separating them out into their own object. I haven't tried this on your code, so it may end up being less concise, but it's good to consider various data structures in anything you write.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use `const` wherever value is not re-assigned

The code makes use of `let` for the majority of the variables. Generally it is wise to Use `const` for variables and then fall back to `let` if the value does need to be re-assigned. This avoids unintentional re-assignment.

#### `getColCards` method

I wonder about the method `getColCards`:

> ```
> getColCards(colid){
>     let cards = this.state.cards.filter( c => c.colid == colid);
>     return cards;
> }
> ```

Why store the filtered array  in `cards` before returning it? Why not just return the filtered list (without the intermediary assignment)? While it isn't an unused variable, I wonder if it was leftover from debugging the value. Some may argue that it is more readable but others may argue that it is pointless to create a variable for a value and then immediately return that value. For more information on this, refer to [these answers on a related topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/340497/244085).

Perhaps naming the method something like `getFilteredColCards()` would maintain readability.

The method could be simplified as follows:

```
getFilteredColCards(colid){
    return this.state.cards.filter( c => c.colid == colid);
}
```

This may not use significantly less memory, but (since it is similar to [this example on the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Return_values#Using_return_values_in_your_own_functions) about return values in functions) it is "*quicker to write, and more compact*"<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Return_values#Using_return_values_in_your_own_functions)</sup>

#### Function partials can be used instead of an extra lambda function

The extra lambda/anonymous functions for the left & right arrow click handlers could be removed by using [`Funtion.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to create a [partially applied function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions):

```
<span onClick = {this.moveCardLeft.bind(this, c)}> {"<   "} </span>
```

and

```
<span onClick = {this.moveCardRight.bind(this, c)}> {"    >"} </span>
```

#### Useless variable

The method `render()` has a variable `cols` but that doesn't appear to be used (though correct me if I am wrong about that). It does appear that `this.state.cols` is used - was `cols` left over from previous code? It appears to be a primitive version of `cols` from the state object.

#### Iterator variable name re-used

The method `render()` has the following lines:

> ```
> let colCards = this.state.cols.map(c => {
> let cards = this.getColCards(c.id).map(c =>  {
> ```

So in both cases `c` is used. When I tried to run the code I saw the warning:

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.
>
> Check the render method of `App`. See https://fb.me/react-warning-keys for more information.

So I added a key to make those `<div>` elements unique and to utilize the outer iterator, I renamed the inner iterator variable `cc`:

```
const colCards = this.state.cols.map(c => {
      const cards = this.getColCards(c.id).map(cc =>  {
        return <div key={c.id + '_' + cc.id}>
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Return_values#Using_return_values_in_your_own_functions</sub>

Comment: I don't agree with your excessive assignment argument. Sure, directly returning an inline operation's result requires less lines of code, but ultimately it's better to assign the operation's result to a variable first so as to name the value you're returning. It's all about readable code.

Comment: I understand your point and have expanded the section